# <div> with a <select> tag does not get posted inside a <form> tag

Tags: html, submit

I have a html structure like this

```
 <form> 
   <div>
     <select name="selectbox">
       <option>option 1</option>
     </select> 
   </div>
 </form>
```

When I do a form submit, I do not see the values of that select, but if I put the select box outside of the div, it posts the value correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: can you show you're actual code?

Comment: Your `<form>` doesn't have an `action` or `method` attribute... ? Or a submit button... Is there some JavaScript missing from the snippet?

Answer (score 1):

That would be because you are missing the value attribute of the option tag. It should be:

```
<select name="variableName">
<option value="serverSideValue">DisplayText</option>
....
</select>
```

The text in between option is simply used for display to the user.